# How to make id match check and display data in view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I have 2 tables, the first with users, the second with files. How to compare user ID and file ID, and then print the file name in View if ID is the same? I'm using ASP.Net Core

[first table with users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spbiJ.png)
[second table with files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEc7q.png)

This is the little part of Controller

```
 var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();
                    string constr = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {
                        string sql = "INSERT INTO UploadFiles (Name,Path,FileId) VALUES (@Name, @Path, @Id)";
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Request.Form.Files[i].FileName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", file);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", userId);
                            conn.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

And the part of view

```
<body>
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model[i].ToString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileName = @Model[i].ToString() })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <p style="position:absolute;top:2.5%;left:70%">Hello,@User.Identity.Name</p>

    <form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff">
        <input class="logout" style="position:absolute;top:-1.5%;left:83%" type="submit" name="" value="Log Out" />
    </form>
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
else
{
    <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="brk-btn" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%">Sign In</a>
    <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" class="brk-btn" style="position:absolute;top:60%;left:48.5%">Registration</a>
}
```

I want to output only those files that a particular user has uploaded, but so far all files are output.

This is my Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public usersContext _context;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var model = _context.UploadFiles.Where(f => f.FileId == userId).ToList();
        //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Files"));
        //for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
        //}
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is the usersContext

```
public partial class usersContext : DbContext
{
    public usersContext()
    {
    }

    public usersContext(DbContextOptions<usersContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UploadFiles> UploadFiles { get; set; }
```

And this is UploadFiles

```
namespace ASPMVCIdentity
{
    public partial class UploadFiles
    {
        public string FileId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a little bit more context - the schema of the tables, the name of the columns that you want to match, the columns that you want to return, are you looking for a SQL script (since you've stated explicitly that you are using ASP.NET core, but it's irrelevent if you need only the SQL statement)

Comment: i'm updated the question

Comment: Well, to be honest, still not entirely sure what exactly is giving you problems here. Since in `UploadFiles` table the `FileId` column actually contains the `UserId` you need to perform this select `SELECT * FROM UploadFiles WHERE FileId = userId` and if you want to use parameterized query (as you should) just make it `FileId = @UserId` and replace the placeholder as you did for the insert query. Is that what you need?

Comment: I have to say your naming convention here is quite strange. If the File belongs to the user then the column should be named UserID, not FileID. Seeing things like Where FileID = userID makes me scratch my head.

Comment: How do you get the data of filelist that is in your provide view ?For more effective suggestions , please share the related code .

Answer (score 0):

Create an SQL view which will join two tables by corresponding IDs.
From you application read the query and show it in UI.
If you need help providing either query for view or reading query results in ASP, please provide names and structures

Answer (score 0):

As Sean Lange commented above, your model relationship is a bit strange . From your description ,there is a one-to-many relationships between `User` model and `File` model.

Here is a simple worked example , you could refer to and  make the modification according to your demand

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<UploadFile> UploadFiles { get; set; }
}

public class UploadFile
{
    [Key]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {  }

    public DbSet<UploadFile> UploadFile { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

The behind-code of getting the FileList corresponding to the logged in user

```
public IActionResult FileList()
{
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var model = _context.UploadFile.Where(f => f.UserId == userId).ToList();
        return View(model);
}
```

The view of Filelist

```
@model List<MVC2_1IndividualProject.Models.UploadFile>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Model[i].Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileName = @Model[i].Name })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

}
```

Comment: Could you help me with my specific example?
Here is my controller for view
I used the entity framework to connect to the database.
He generated me usersContext and UploadFiles.
I create the user context object in my controller and use your code to fetch the ID, but the intellisense says that the _context is null.  I added the screenshots of UploadFiles and usersContext to the question

Comment: @YauheniLazakovich , you should inject the DbContext in your HomeController like injecting `IHostingEnvironment ` .